# OutOfMemoryError with IntelliJ12 IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Have set heap size to use 2096 in IntelliJ12.

```
Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Maximum heap size (MB).
```

But still I get '*Error:java: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*' , when I tried compiling simple Java class.  It use to compile fine with IntelliJ 11 .

Couldn't able to figure out why it is taking long time [ as seen in status bar - it does full 'Parsing java...' & tries compiling ] & failing after 5+ min.s as opposed to few seconds with IntelliJ11.

Also, it works just fine with compilation from command line with javac.

Adding stacktrace:

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_25 to compile java sources
Information:java: The system is out of resources.
Information:java: Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java:   at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:642)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.storeEnd(EndPosParser.java:64)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.toP(EndPosParser.java:77)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term3(JavacParser.java:1008)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term2(JavacParser.java:701)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term1(JavacParser.java:672)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:628)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.term(JavacParser.java:610)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseType(JavacParser.java:604)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.catchTypes(JavacParser.java:1888)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.catchClause(JavacParser.java:1876)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseStatement(JavacParser.java:1771)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.blockStatements(JavacParser.java:1598)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:1561)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.block(JavacParser.java:1575)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.methodDeclaratorRest(JavacParser.java:2696)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(JavacParser.java:2645)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceBody(JavacParser.java:2573)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classDeclaration(JavacParser.java:2421)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceOrEnumDeclaration(JavacParser.java:2362)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.typeDeclaration(JavacParser.java:2351)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit(JavacParser.java:2289)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.parseCompilationUnit(EndPosParser.java:83)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:595)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:632)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:909)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:165)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:364)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:276)
Information:java: **Errors occurred while compiling module 'PROJ-NAME'**
Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 8 min 32 sec
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
**Error:java: OutOfMemoryError: insufficient memory**
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for [the IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA), along with a proper test case demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Post your "simple Java class" if you can.

Comment: Even simple hello world program has this problem and as an eg. I just tried this small program compilation & I see same behavior. 

public class MyImpl
{
    public static void main(String av[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello IntelliJ12!!");
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable the GWT compiler?

You can turn off the module check boxes, which are found at `Project Structure -> Facets -> GWT`

While it isn't usually helpful with OOM errors, please post your stack trace.

Comment: I disabled it by traversing to Settings->Plugin->GWT Support . And reopened IntelliJ12. Still it is taking lot of time & failing with OOM error. Added stacktrace to my question above